# When I click on XPM button its goes to XPM (site edit) mode in SDL web 8.5 but the fields are not editable

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5, sdl-tridion

Please find a screenshot below:

[image]

This is a .Net application. I'm using Razor and DWT Templates.

Here is the source of the published page (taken from the pastebin URL in the comments below) which seems to contain the correct XPM tags:

```
<html>
<head>
  Inline page
</head>
<body>
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:18-9360" templateURI="tcm:18-9357-32"><span><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:18-9360", "ComponentModified" : "2018-03-27T00:43:06", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:18-9357-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2018-03-27T12:59:23", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false } -->
  <span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:InlineEditingTestschema/custom:Title[1]"} -->
    TEst
  </span>
  <span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:InlineEditingTestschema/custom:Description[1]"} -->
    <p>cdasfasfsd</p>
<p>fsdfsdfsdfsd</p>
<p>fsdfsdfsf</p>
  </span>
</span></tcdl:ComponentPresentation>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="http://localhost:81/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thoufik, Please provide some more information like - XPM tags that you have used, configurations and also the log.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the HTML source of the page?

Comment: use https://pastebin.com/ to provide the html source and link URL here

Comment: After updated tag this is latest source file  https://pastebin.com/1137x7Fz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following steps to resolving this issue.

1. Ensure **"Enable inline editing for Page"** TBB added in your page template using template builder and then on the right, select **SiteEdit Editor URL** and set it to the value **http://localhost:81/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/**
2. In the **General** tab ensure that **Enable for inline editing** is selected for Page Template.
3. Also, ensure that the following comment is inserted into your end of Page Template code.

> <!--SITE_EDIT_INIT-->

This will render the missing Page Settings tag as highlighted by @Jonathan.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its working fine tks

Answer (score 2):

This looks like your page is created based on "Default Page Template", which, I am quite sure, doesn't have XPM markup. Please change page template to some yours which you know has markup and test again.

**Update:**

[Following documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-99143B2A-5B69-4EED-B470-DD70559AE616&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-CB231A4D-2EA4-4A0E-A6AA-B496B6490EFD.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-99143B2A-5B69-4EED-B470-DD70559AE616&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dexperience%2520manager&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1522148551832&currentQuery=experience%2520manager&currentScope=) explains proper XPM syntax.

Can you please verify that you wrote `@@FieldStartMarker@@` and `@@FieldEndMarker@@`  tags?

Comment: @@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
  @@GetFieldValue('Component.Fields.Title', 0)@@
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@  

@@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
  @@GetFieldValue('Component.Fields.Description', 0)@@
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@                                                                  this is tag we are using Component Tbb and also i removed default TBB but still same issues persist

Comment: Verified as per the shared docs. Updated and published but still no luck. But 1 more concern "Enable inline editing page TBB" should be get part installation but when restoring DB we lost. How we can get TBB ?   just uploaded dll "Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating.dll"  then we got "Enable Inline Editing Content" TBB same dll needs to use for Page TBB aslo please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTML source that you uploaded to Pastebin (now included in the question), it appears that your missing the XPM markup needed on the page. For example:

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:9-259-64","PageModified":"2016-08-04T14:43:31","PageTemplateID":"tcm:9-264-128","PageTemplateModified":"2016-10-18T12:37:03"} -->
```

This is normally found just above the Bootstrap Javascript tag at the bottom of the page.

You may want to check the TBBs and markup that you're using on the Page Template.